# Converting JSON variables to lowercase in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, wcf, json

I'm using the JSONPEncoderFactory,JSONPBehavior solution to enable JSONP in WCF. That's all fine, it's all set up and working well, my service returns the data correctly, no problems there.

However, I need to be able to force the JSON variable names into lowercase due to the way they are being used in JS, and this is something I haven't been able to figure out as yet.

Here is an example of my service output (the variable names and values have been changed to benign elements for this example)

```
{"Animals":["dog","cat","mouse"],"Owner":"Greg","Permanent":"y","ID":1,"DaysToStay":"1"}
```

Pretty simple right? I want the "Animals" to be "animals", and so on...

Do I need to use a json parser for this, or is it easy enough just to use a regular expression? I'd be grateful if someone could let me know how they've done this before.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using DataContract based serialization? If so, you can decorate your property with [DataMember("animals")] etc.

Comment: If you are generating this in C# you can use `.ToLower()` on the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function on JavaScript:

```
FN = function (obj)
{
    var ret = null;
    if (typeof(obj) == "string" || typeof(obj) == "number")
        return obj;
    else if (obj.push)
        ret = [];
    else
        ret = {};

    for (var key in obj)
        ret[String(key).toLowerCase()] = FN(obj[key]);
    return ret;
};
```

EDIT:
Deserialize a json string in a Dictionary with C#:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dic = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,dynamic>>(yourJSONString);
```

The complex fields will be deserialized into Dictionary. So you will ned a recursive function for inspect the matherialized dic.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this looks like a JavaScript function. I'm really looking for a way to do this in ASP.NET just before the stream gets returned from the service as JSON.

Comment: In C# you can desserialize your json string in a Dictionary. Iterate over it and then, build a new dictionary with your keys in lower case.